# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. can not load font-awesome fonts

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, fonts

I have created a critical path for my website and have set the URL's within the critical path to absolute values as I've seen suggested. However I am receiving the follwing error.

"Redirect from 'http://example.com/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.3.0' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://www.example.com' is therefore not allowed access."

I have tried to change the Access-control-allow-origin in my .htaccess file to "http://example.com" but this breaks my site and causes a internal 500 error. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: any news on that ?